# Strange compile error in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to pass a variable of the type:

`HashMap<Foo, HashSet<Bar>>`

to a method, which expects:

`Map<Foo, Set<Bar>>`

I think it should work, but I'm getting the following compile error:

```
java: method setMenu in class com.xx.client.layout.Layout cannot be applied to given types;

  required: java.util.Map<com.xx.shared.model.UserType,java.util.Set<com.xx.shared.dto.model.MenuItemDTO>>

  found: java.util.HashMap<com.xx.shared.model.UserType,java.util.HashSet<com.xx.shared.dto.model.MenuItemDTO>>

  reason: actual argument java.util.HashMap<com.xx.shared.model.UserType,java.util.HashSet<com.xx.shared.dto.model.MenuItemDTO>> 

cannot be converted to 

java.util.Map<com.xx.shared.model.UserType,java.util.Set<com.xx.shared.dto.model.MenuItemDTO>> 

by method invocation conversion
```

Comment: The same way that a `List<Dog>` is not a sub type of `List<Animal>`, a `HashMap<..,HashSet<..>>` is not a sub type of a `Map<..,Set<..>>`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Its not a sub-type, but if a method expects a `Map`, then I should be able to pass a `HashMap` to it because `HashMap` implements `Map`

Comment: No, type safety causes a failure in this case because the types are not compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To attempt to convince you, given a

```
HashMap<Foo, HashSet<Bar>> myMap;
```

you would expect to do

```
HashSet<Bar> aHashSet = myMap.get(aFoo);
```

But if you had

```
public void someMethod(Map<Foo, Set<Bar>> aMapParameter) {...}
```

and expected

```
someMethod(myMap);
```

to work, then `someMethod` could simply do

```
public void someMethod(Map<Foo, Set<Bar>> aMapParameter) {
    aMapParameter.put(aFoo, new TreeSet<>());
}
```

Your original

```
HashSet<Bar> aHashSet = myMap.get(aFoo);
```

would fail with a `ClassCastException`.

Compile time type safety has to guarantee that this doesn't happen. Therefore the compiler doesn't allow that method call.

Related:

- [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)